# Ввести с клавиатуры одномерный массив целых чисел. Вывести на экран элементы массива, значение которых встречается более одного раза

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, циклы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *mas=new int[25];
    int N;
    cout << "Input N" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    int *p = new int[N];
    cout << "Input array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> p[i];
        cout << i << " Element of array = " << p[i] << endl;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (p[i] == p[i + 1]||p[i]==p[i+i])
        {
            mas[i] = p[i];
        }       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << mas[i];
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`mas[i]` присвоили те элементы массива  которые повторяются но выводит всякий мусор, подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: В чем состоит смысл использования логического оператора ИЛИ ( || ) в этом выражении  p[i] == p[i + 1]||p[i]==p[i+i])?

Comment: я не знаю какое в этом месте поставить условие по-этому поставил такую. Возможно вы знаете как должно быть на самом деле ??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, ваше задание на умение работать с массивами и циклами и до стандартных контейнеров и алгоритмов дело еще не дошло.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом. Только в представленной демонстрационной программе я не ввожу элементы массива с клавиатуры. а генерирую их случайные значения. Вам самому придется изменить программу так. чтобы пользователь задавал размерность массива сам, чтобы массив выделялся динамически, и затем пользователь вводил элементы массива. Не забудьте при этом в конце программы удалить этот массив оператором `delete []`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &x : a  ) x = std::rand() % N;

    for ( auto x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j != i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

        if ( j++ == i )
        {
            while ( j < N && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

            if ( j != N ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы может выглядеть примерно так

```
1 2 9 5 0 5 2 4 1 8 
1 2 5
```

Принцип работы следуюший. Если есть очередной элемент массива с индексом `i`, то мы смотрим имели мы с его значением дело уже ранее, рассматривая элементы в диапазоне `[0, i)`. Если уже имели с его значением дело, то просто пропускаем его. Иначе смотрим, попадается ли в диапазоне `[i+1, N)` еще элемент с таким же значением. Если да, то выводим его на консоль.

Если же разрешается изменять порядок элементов в массиве после их ввода, то вы можете отсортировать массив, используя стандартный алгоритм `std::sort` следующим образом

```
std::sort( a, a + N );
```

включив предварительно заголовок

```
#include <algorithm>
```

а затем вывести последовательно элементы, которые совпадают по значению с рядом стоящими элементами. Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &x : a  ) x = std::rand() % N;

    for ( auto x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( a, a + N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; )
    {
        size_t j = i + 1;

        while ( j < N && a[i] == a[j] ) j++;

        if ( j - i > 1 )
        {
            std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
        }

        i = j;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Что касается представленного вами кода, то по крайней мере данный цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (p[i] == p[i + 1]||p[i]==p[i+i])
    {
        mas[i] = p[i];
    }       
}
```

ведет к неопределенному поведению программы, так как в условии

```
    if (p[i] == p[i + 1]||p[i]==p[i+i])
```

которое к тому же не имеет смысла происходит выход за границу массива, адресуемым указателем `p`, при `i` равным `N-1`, и к тому же не всем элементам массива, адресуемого указателем `mas`, будут присвоены значения. А этот массив изначально не инициализирован, а потому содержит неопределенные значения..